# After I close NerdTree window, MiniBufExplorer being activated, not a previously active window(before toggling NerdTree)

Tags: vim, nerdtree, vim-plugin, minibufexplorer

I'm using NERDTreeToggle function to open NERDTree window, when I'm closing it(with the same function), miniBufExplorer activates, but not the window which I'm been edited before opened NERDTree. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When I look at [the plugins site](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) I notice that miniBufExplorer was updated 2004 last time. Possibly it's outdated and has compatibility issues with vim 7. I'd suggest to replace it with [buftabs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1664), which works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to the way Vim behaves; when you close a window, Vim does not move to the last active window. Unfortunately, there's no way around this, as it isn't really viable to remember the "last active window" from Vim's perspective; window ids are not constant in vim, so there's no reliable way to script the exact behaviour you want.